# jquery flyout "slide" effect seems to grow.

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to copy the way the new menu on amazon flys out. I am using this for my menu currently:

http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/wordpress-plugins/wordpress-tutorial-create-your-own-custom-vertical-mega-menu/

As you can see here the menu seems to fly out AND grow at the same time instead of just fly out. Can anyone identify why it is also growing?

Comment: Please post the relevant code here and not a link to an external site. Keeping the code here helps future visitors in the event of the site you're referencing being unavailable.

Comment: hmm Ok I will try to update to post just the relevent code... I am not sure what causes the growing effect though so there is a lot of code where it could be..

Answer (score 0):

Because when you mouse over a link the menu is initially setting the width and height to zero for the sub-menu and then animating both parameters to the required size.

If you dont want the animation effect you can either use the fade in option or just show/hide.

Comment: The effect I was going for was the one on the current amazon.com site. It flys out but does not grow.

Comment: Then just animate the width - set initial width to zero and animate to required width of sub-menu. If using the dcverticalmegamenu.1.3.js plugin just remove lines 177 & 193